# Updating of records in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new bie to hibernate and i am facing one issue.
I have fetched the record from database and displayed the values on Jsp form.

I want to update some of the values i have displayed

I made the ID of the entity hidden form field.

When i click on submit the values which are not on form are set to be null.

Everytime i have to update the record i have to manually set all the values again to the object and then save

Example

I have user entity having the following fields
    Id
    firstName
    lastName
    dateUpdated
    dateCreated

In my jsp i have only two fields 
    firstName 
    lastName
and on hidden form field
Id

In my controller i am creating new obj of User and setting these three values
I am updating my record using merge method.

on merging 
DateCreated and dateUpdated are getting null!

How can i achieve it without fetching the record and setting the modified value and then saving it

Regards
Ramandeep S

Answer (score 0):

```
User user;
session = //Open a session
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.idEq(id));
List<T> objList = criteria.list();
if(objList == null || objList.size() == 0) {
}
else {
    user = objList.get(0);
}
//user.setproperties() //etc
//save it using the session
```

You need to fetch the object from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Either load the object and update using hibernate (the safest method) OR run a traditional update query i.e. sql
The second method might be faster but runs the risk of not updating anything if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have "employee" object that you want to update into your database.

Steps :

1. Before updating,fetch the employee object from the database
   employee = getEmployee(id);
2. Once you get the employee object.update your entry and then save it like :
   employee.setName("XYZ") ;
   updateEmployee(employee);

Here you don't have to set each and every value again and again.